# Using color scales as axes in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

I'm trying to create a visualization that varies color (specifically the H and V values of an HSV color scheme while keeping S constant), while representing the response of a given function to those colors.

Effectively, it's a heat map where the x and y axes are colors rather than numbers. Hunting through the matplotlib gallery I can find a lot of examples based on colorbars such as those found [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/colorbar_tick_labelling_demo.html), and [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/colorbar_basics.html).

The colorbar implementation is close to what I'm looking for, with these important caveats:

1. I'm looking to align the colors as ticks on the main figure, rather than adding ticks to the colorbar itself. Principally this calls for making sure the plot and the colorbar are aligned, and I haven't found any way of actually guaranteeing this.
2. I'm trying to ensure that the color bar will display on the left of the figure (in place of the standard x-axis) rather than to the right.

The second point sounds trivial, but I haven't found any documented way of achieving it unfortunately.

Is there any way of creating a plot like this in matplotlib that would be considerably less effort than creating it from scratch in `d3` or a similar lower-level visualization library?

Comment: Just wondering if you can clarify "a heat map where the x and y axes are colors rather than numbers". Not sure about others, but I feel difficult to imagine the figure in your mind. Specifically, what are the data in the graph, if neither axes are numbers? For example, how do I know what color to show at the classic position (1,0)?

Comment: The data in the graph is numeric. So basically think of a function that takes in a color and returns a number from zero to one. If it's easier to imagine, you can think that the x-axis is blue and the y-axis is blue. The function can be an intensity measure of the resulting color. The actual result is the output of a machine learning model.

Comment: @Y.Luo The color to show at (1,0) would be the response to pure blue. You can just assume that I've got an array of values that would fit into the graph itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not quite sure about it; but I'll give a try. Sorry if I misunderstood it.

Major thoughts are using `GridSpec` to solve your two requirements: aligning the "color axes" and put them beside the classic axes. The alignment should be correct because corresponding axes between `ax_x`/`ax_y` and the main `ax` are the same.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import hsv_to_rgb
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
import numpy as np

# Create a spectrum sample
# Convert HSV to RGB so that matplotlib can plot;
# hsv_to_rgb assumes values to be in range [0, 1]
N = 0.001
v_y, h_x = np.mgrid[0:1:N, 0:1:N]
c = hsv_to_rgb(np.stack([h_x, np.ones(h_x.shape), v_y], axis=2))
c_x = hsv_to_rgb(np.stack([h_x, np.ones(h_x.shape), np.zeros(v_y.shape)], axis=2))
c_y = hsv_to_rgb(np.stack([np.zeros(h_x.shape), np.ones(h_x.shape), v_y], axis=2))

fig = plt.figure()
# Ratio to adjust width for "x axis" and "y axis"
fig_ratio = np.divide(*fig.get_size_inches())
gs = GridSpec(2, 2, wspace=0.0, hspace=0.0,
              width_ratios=[1, 20], height_ratios=[20/fig_ratio, 1])
# Lower-left corner is ignored
ax_y = plt.subplot(gs[0])
ax = plt.subplot(gs[1])
ax_x = plt.subplot(gs[3])

# Image are stretched to fit the ax since numbers are hided or not important in this figure.
img = ax.imshow(c, aspect='auto', origin='lower')
# Colorbar on img won't give correct results since it is plot with raw RGB values
img_x = ax_x.imshow(c_x, aspect='auto', origin='lower')
img_y = ax_y.imshow(c_y, aspect='auto', origin='lower')
# Remove ticks and ticklabels
for ax in [ax_y, ax, ax_x]:
    ax.tick_params(left=False, bottom=False, 
                   labelleft=False, labelbottom=False)

plt.show()
```

[image]

## Response to the comment:

> To clarify, you're making three plots, and using imshow plots as axes by assigning them to quadrants of the grid?

Yes, it's a 2x2 grid and I ignored the lower-left one. The documentation might not be great but what I did is similar to [this part](https://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html#gridspec-and-subplotspec).

> And presumably if I wanted to add space between the axes here and the main plot I would increase wspace and hspace?

Yes, it is briefly demonstrated in [this part](https://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html#adjust-gridspec-layout) of documentation. Besides, I adjusted it with `width_ratios` and `height_ratios` so that 3 parts of the figure are not the same size, like [this](https://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html#gridspec-with-varying-cell-sizes).

> Also, just to confirm, there is a fully black axis on the bottom of this image, and it's not a misalignment of the left axis.

The bottom is the colored x axis. It is black because I thought it corresponds to `v=0`. If you change

```
c_x = hsv_to_rgb(np.stack([h_x, np.ones(h_x.shape), np.zeros(v_y.shape)], axis=2))
```

to

```
c_x = hsv_to_rgb(np.stack([h_x, np.ones(h_x.shape), np.ones(v_y.shape)], axis=2))
```

You would get this figure, proving it's not misaligned:

[image]

> If it's easier, you can also ignore the whole hsv thing, use a gray box or something as the central image.

I'm sorry but I'm really slow on this. I'm still having no idea what you want to show in the figure. So I don't know how to help. If you remove or comment out the line

```
img = ax.imshow(c, aspect='auto', origin='lower')
```

You got this:

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is what I'm looking for, but the Gridspec docs are bad enough that I'm not quite certain. To clarify, you're making three plots, and using imshow plots as axes by assigning them to quadrants of the grid?

And presumably if I wanted to add space between the axes here and the main plot I would increase wspace and hspace?

Also, just to confirm, there is a fully black axis on the bottom of this image, and it's not a misalignment of the left axis.

If it's easier, you can also ignore the whole hsv thing, use a gray box or something as the central image.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus Honestly, I still don't know what exactly should I provide. Tried again to address your comments in the answer. Could you please check it again?